# GNU Makefile why need eval in some custom functions?

Tags: gnu-make

I have a Makefile and an a/makefile.mk:

```makefile
.SUFFIXES:

.PHONY: all
all:

bldroot := /tmp/a

# create a recipe
# parameters:
# - $1 source file (.s, .c)
# - $2 source dir
# - $3 build dir
define makerec
  src := $2/$1

  assrc := $(filter %.s,$(src))
  csrc := $(filter %.c,$(src))
  bld := $3/$(assrc:.s=.o)$(csrc:.c=o)

  mkdir := $(mkdir) $(3)
  all: $(bld)

  $(if $(assrc),
$(bld) : $(src) | $(3)
    @echo AS $$@ $$<
  )

  $(if $(csrc),
$(bld) : $(src) | $(3);
    @echo CC $$@ $$<
  )


endef

# include all makefile.mk
# parameters
# - $1 makefile.mk
define inclmk
$(info --- $1)
  $(eval srcdir := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $1)))
  $(eval blddir := $(abspath $(bldroot)/$(subst /src/,/bld/,$(srcdir))))
  $(eval srcdir := $(abspath $(srcdir)))
  $(eval srcs :=)
  $(eval include $1)
$(info +++ $(srcdir))
$(info $(srcs))
  $(foreach s,$(srcs),$(eval $(call makerec,$s,$(srcdir),$(blddir))))
endef

# find all mamakefile.mks
rwildcard = $(foreach d,$(wildcard $(1:=/*)),$(call rwildcard,$d,$2) \
  $(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))
mkfiles := $(call rwildcard,.,*/makefile.mk)
$(foreach f,$(mkfiles),$(eval $(call inclmk,$f)))

# create build directory structure
mkdir := $(sort $(mkdir))
$(mkdir):
    mkdir -p $@

# clean
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(bldroot)
```

```makefile
srcs := a.s
```

And an empty a/a.s.

In a directory structure like this:

```
.
|-- Makefile
`-- a
    |-- a.s
    `-- makefile.mk
```

Why makerec function works without evals and why inclmk doesn't?
Without eval it doesn't do even variable assignments.

The `$(info +++ $(srcdir))` line only prints the plus signs if `$(eval srcdir := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $1)))` is without eval.
Why `srcdir := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $1))` doesn't work?

I couldn't get the difference between makerec and inclmk.

Answer (score 2):

Wow you've really jumped into the deep end of the pool here.  Let's splash back into the shallow end for a minute and take a lesson or two first.

Let's reduce our focus to this part:

```
$(eval $(call inclmk,$f))
```

What does this do, really?  Well, as in all things make, macros (and functions) are expanded "inside out".  That means that *first* `$f` is expanded, then `$(call inclmk,xxx.mk)` (if `$f` expands to `xxx.mk`) is expanded, then `$(eval <results-of-call-expansion>)` is expanded.

We can see, therefore, that before `eval` ever gets its hands on the content of the `inclmk` variable value, it's already been expanded, by `call`.

Let's use an example `Makefile`:

```
define inclmk
$(info call: $1)
$$(info eval: $1)
endef

$(info expanding call)
callex := $(call inclmk,hi)

$(info expanding eval)
$(eval $(callex))
```

When you run `make` with this makefile, you get:

```
$ make
expanding call
call: hi
expanding eval
eval: hi
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

What is happening here?  We've first done the `call` (using `:=` so it's expanded immediately) then we've done the `eval` on the results.  We can see that the `$(info call: $1)` is expanded immediately, but the `$$(info eval: $1)` is not expanded until later during the `eval`.  Let's add a bit of detail so we can see what the results of the `call` is; add this line to the end of the makefile:

```
$(info results of call: "$(callex)")
```

Now you'll see this extra output printed:

```
results of call: "
$(info eval: hi)"
```

Where did the `$(info call: $1)` go?  It was expanded to print that output when the `call` function was expanded, so it's gone.  Since we escaped the second `$$(info eval: $f)` the expansion of this was `$(info eval: hi)` so we see that in the output.

Then we run `eval` on that, and it prints the second `info`.

So now let's look at (part of) your makefile and take back out the inner `eval`:

```
define inclmk
$(info --- $1)
  srcdir := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $1))
  blddir := $(abspath $(bldroot)/$(subst /src/,/bld/,$(srcdir)))
  srcdir := $(abspath $(srcdir))
  srcs :=
  include $1
$(info +++ $(srcdir))
$(info $(srcs))
endef
```

I've left out the inner `foreach` as it's too complicated for me to think about right now.  As above, you use this in two phases: first it's expanded by `call`, then the results of that expansion are expanded by `eval`.  Only `eval` actually parses make syntax: `call` is a simple text substitution operation it doesn't know anything about variable assignment etc.

So let's suppose that the value of `$1` is `xxx.mk`.  Then after the first expansion, using `call`, the result will be:

```
  srcdir := xxx.mk
  blddir := 
  srcdir := 
  srcs :=
  include xxx.mk
```

Why is this?  Because the expansion all happens during `call`, but the assignment doesn't happen until later, during `eval`.  That means that when make expands the value on the right of `bindir` and tries to use the value of `srcdir`, that variable hasn't been set yet (it won't be set until the `eval`) and is the empty string, and so `blddir` is empty.  Etc.

So what do you do to make this work?  Well the answer is suggested in my example above: for any macro or function that you want `eval` to see, you have to *escape* it from `call`.  Put simply, only the `call` argument variables like `$1`, `$2`, etc. should be *un*-escaped in the `define` macro.  Everything else should be escaped.  So you should write your `define` like this:

```
define inclmk
$$(info --- $1)
  srcdir := $$(patsubst %/,%,$$(dir $1))
  blddir := $$(abspath $$(bldroot)/$$(subst /src/,/bld/,$$(srcdir)))
  srcdir := $$(abspath $$(srcdir))
  srcs :=
  include $1
$$(info +++ $$(srcdir))
$$(info $$(srcs))
endef
```

Then it will work as you expect.

Comment: Thank you! I read it a few times, so I think, I understand it. Only one thing, I can't understand: how works ```makerec``` function without evals or escapes? What is the difference between ```makerec``` and ```inclmk```?

Comment: `makerec` also won't work without escaping.

Comment: it works somehow; only recipe lines have got escaping

Comment: I'm 100% confident it doesn't really work.  It might seem to work, or partly work.  For example, the first time through the `foreach` loop the value of `src` is not set and so the results are wrong.  But the next time through the loop, the value of `src` is set to the results of the _previous_ time through the loop, and so the second iteration defines the values for the first iteration, then the third iteration defines the values for the second, etc.  Thus eventually all except the last iteration are defined, by accident.

Comment: The easiest way to debug `eval` issues is, as it says in the manual, replace `eval` with `info` then you'll see what make is evaluating.  So if you add this to your makefile: `$(foreach s,$(srcs),$(info $(call makerec,$s,$(srcdir),$(blddir))))` you will see the rules make actually evaluates.